# mutlipe buttons choice android

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I'm wondering how to make multiple buttons, which have the ability to go back after a certain amount of clicks. when i hit the third incorrect button it doesn't go back. please can someone tell me where im going wrong.
after the third attempt it should close the activity

```
private boolean answer = false;
private int turnsLeft = 0;
Button btn1;
Button btn2;
Button btn3;
Button btn4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cat);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick (View view){
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btn1: {
            Intent intent  = new Intent(Cat.this,Congratulations.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.btn2: {
           animalButtonClicked(btn2,turnsLeft);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.btn3: {
            animalButtonClicked(btn3,turnsLeft);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.btn4: {
            animalButtonClicked(btn4,turnsLeft);
            break;
        }
        default:{
            break;
        }
    }
}

private int animalButtonClicked(Button button, int count){
    button.setEnabled(false);
    count++;


    if(count == 3){
        count = 0;
        finish();
    }
    button.setEnabled(false);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: and what is the situation when it should go back... :)

Comment: should change activity after 3 attempt

Answer (score 0):

You are passing turnsLeft global variable to the method. But incrementing only the local variable "count". It does not affect the global variable. So the turnsLeft is always 0.

change your code like this for all buttons click,

```
animalButtonClicked(btn2, ++turnsLeft);
```

and remove the line `count++` from the method.

Another solution is not at all to pass the global variable "turnsLeft" to the method. As it is a global variable, you could access the variable turnsLeft directly inside the method, instead of using the local variable "count".